# Jquery Dialog Youtube ( Pause / Resume )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, youtube

**IDEA**

Want to open a dialog with youtube video, play when I open when i close the dialog box , want to pause it and then continue when i reopen.

**PROBLEM**

Chrome supposed been working +-, but firefox seems having some problem always loading when I open the dialog.

Created this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/beaM4/1/)

PS- not sure how trough embebed can access the video to pause.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the YouTube JavaScript API? It's far more configurable than trying to use the basic embedded player

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html